# Android minimal Bitmap loader

Tags: android, bitmap

I need the minimal Android bitmap loader. This code throw NullPointerException("Unable to start activity ComponentInfo"):

```
package com.example.testbitmap;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.widget.ImageView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        String photoPath = "/storage/sdcard0/Pictures/image.jpeg";
        Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(photoPath);
        ImageView iv = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1); 
        iv.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
        setContentView(iv);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
ImageView iv = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1); 
iv.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
setContentView(iv);
```

you should `setContentView();` another layout(as `iv` should be in the layout) or create `iv` instead of finding it

Also, put `setContentView` before any `findViewById` calls

Answer (score 1):

You always have to set your layout first in you activity after that you can access the views of your layout..

Whereas you have accessed your view first and then after set the layout which is wrong. 
Do the changes in your onCreate() as below:

> ```
>     setContentView(R.layout.mylayout); //provide your layout file name where your ImageView resides.
>     ImageView iv = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1); 
>     iv.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
> ```

OR

If you want to dynamically create `ImageView` and then you want to set it as `View` then do as below:

> ```
>   ImageView iv =new ImageView(); 
>     setContentView(iv);
>      iv.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
> ```